# How to split column with double information (abs. value and %) into 2 separated columns?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr

In the dataframe absolute values and percentages are combined, and I want to split them into 2 separated columns:

```
df <- data.frame (Sales  = c("74(2.08%)",
                             "71(2.00%)",
                             "58(1.63%)",
                             "42(1.18%)"))

      Sales
1 74(2.08%)
2 71(2.00%)
3 58(1.63%)
4 42(1.18%)
```

Expected output

```
  Sales Share
1    74  2.08
2    71  2.00
3    58  1.63
4    42  1.18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Base R:

```
read.table(text=gsub("[()%]", ' ', df$Sales), col.names = c("Sales", "Share"))
  Sales Share
1    74  2.08
2    71  2.00
3    58  1.63
4    42  1.18

df %>% 
  separate(Sales, c("Sales", "Share"), sep='[()%]', extra = 'drop', convert = TRUE)

  Sales Share
1    74  2.08
2    71  2.00
3    58  1.63
4    42  1.18
```

Comment: Haha. yeah. Both of these options are much simpler than mine. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyr::extract` you could split your column into separate columns using a regex:

```r
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  extract(Sales, into = c("Sales", "Share"), regex = "^(\\d+)\\((\\d+\\.\\d+)\\%\\)$", convert = TRUE)
#>   Sales Share
#> 1    74  2.08
#> 2    71  2.00
#> 3    58  1.63
#> 4    42  1.18
```